# Assign variable for txt file downloaded via FTP with createWriteStream

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp, aws-lambda, fs

I am trying to download a .txt file via FTP and then assign this file to a variable where I can edit the text later on in the code.

Unsure how to set a variable that can be used outside of the FTP code block, when it is created from createWriteStream in Node.js.

How can I pass this ,txt into the variable `ftpItem` and then access this outside of the FTP function?

The error returned by AWS Lambda is `ftpItem is not defined` - In summary, I am trying to download a TXT file via FTP. Place it in the /tmp/ directory of the AWS Lambda function and then open and edit that text later in the code.

```
var fullPath = event.line_items[0].meta_data[2].value.tmp_name; 
const extension = path.extname(fullPath); 
const FileName = path.basename(fullPath, extension); 
const FileNameWithExtension = path.basename(fullPath); 

...

async function example() {
    const client = new ftp.Client()
    client.ftp.verbose = true
    try {
        await client.access({
            host: process.env.FTP_HOST,
            user: process.env.FTP_USERNAME,
            password: process.env.FTP_PASSWORD,
        })
        console.log(await client.list())
        await client.download(fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/' + FileNameWithExtension), FileNameWithExtension)
        var ftpItem = FileNameWithExtension.Body.toString('ascii');
        console.log(ftpItem);
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    client.close()
}

...

// Use the variable ftpItem outside of the FTP call
// Also tried the following with the same error above
await client.download(fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/' + FileNameWithExtension), FileNameWithExtension)
        {
          var ftpItem = download.Body.toString('ascii');
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable at a higher scope:

```
var fullPath = event.line_items[0].meta_data[2].value.tmp_name; 
const extension = path.extname(fullPath); 
const FileName = path.basename(fullPath, extension); 
const FileNameWithExtension = path.basename(fullPath); 
let ftpItem
...

async function example() {
    const client = new ftp.Client()
    client.ftp.verbose = true
    try {
        await client.access({
            host: process.env.FTP_HOST,
            user: process.env.FTP_USERNAME,
            password: process.env.FTP_PASSWORD,
        })
        console.log(await client.list())
        await client.download(fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/' + FileNameWithExtension), FileNameWithExtension)
        // asign the variable here
        ftpItem = FileNameWithExtension.Body.toString('ascii');
        console.log(ftpItem);
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    client.close()
}

...

// Use the variable ftpItem outside of the FTP call
// Also tried the following with the same error above
await client.download(fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/' + FileNameWithExtension), FileNameWithExtension)
        {
          // Here you can use ftpItem
          console.log(ftpItem)
        }
```